# java swing n mouselistener

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, mouselistener

i have a problem with my java's program well here is the program;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestGraphic extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
  JFrame az=new JFrame();
  JPanel er=new JPanel();
  Point a=new Point(220,300);
  Rectangle r1;
  Cercle c1;
  int x,y;
  Graphics g;

  static void changeColor(Figure o) {
    Color [] tab = Color.black, Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green,
                   Color.magenta,Color.orange,Color.yellow};

    for (int i=0; i<tab.length - 1; i++) {
      if (o.getColor() == tab[i]) {
         o.setColor(tab[i+1]);
         break;
      }
    }
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {      
    if (r1.contains(e.getX(),e.getY() )==true) {    
       changeColor(r1);
       r1.draw(g);
    }

    if (c1.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())==true) {
    }
    //else{r1.setColor(Color.green);
    //r1.draw(g);}
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}

  public TestGraphic() {  
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    r1=new Rectangle(a,30,70);
    c1=new Cercle(150,150,200);
    Cercle c2=new Cercle(185,180,40);
    Cercle c3=new Cercle(265,180,40);

    r1.setColor(Color.blue);
    c1.setColor(Color.yellow);
    c2.setColor(Color.green);
    c3.setColor(Color.red);

    c1.draw(g);
    c2.draw(g);
    c3.draw(g);
    r1.draw(g);

    if(r1.getColor()==Color.cyan) {
      r1.draw(g);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    TestGraphic aap=new TestGraphic();
  }
}
```

in the method `mouseclicked()` when i click the color of the rectangle should change i used `r1.draw(g)` but it's not working :s

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

i tried `repaint()` but it's not working to 
any help ?? :d

Comment: Format your code properly. Then post the complete exception stack trace and tell us which line it reefers to.

Comment: Post an http://sscce.org/

Comment: We need a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

you set the rectangles in your paint method and accessing them inside change color, that means you probably run into an NPE when they are not initalized.

Declare your objects outside of paint and set their properties inside.
For better understanding of paint look [here](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/javainsel/javainsel_14_009.html) or at least add a counter to this method and watch how many times it will be called, to gain a better understanding what happens there.

Also i think that:

```
Color [] tab = Color.black, Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green,
               Color.magenta,Color.orange,Color.yellow};
```

should be:

```
Color [] tab = new Color[]{Color.black, Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green,
               Color.magenta,Color.orange,Color.yellow};
```